# Tycho resolves the wrong version of my own manifest-first artifacts

Tags: maven, tycho

Consider the following scenario: My application has some dependencies on my own POM-first artifacts (built with pure Maven) and some dependencies on my own manifest-first artifacts (built with Tycho). For the POM-first artifacts, Tycho resolves the exact the version I specified in the POM. For the manifest-first artifacts, Tycho resolves the locally built units which may have a higher version.

In my concrete case, I specified a dependency in the pom.xml to the manifest-first artifact in version 1.2.0, but I get warning "The following locally built units have been used to resolve project dependencies" with version 1.3.0.2012xxx.

I have already found following bugs and discussions, but I don't understand why there is a difference in Tycho resolving POM-first and manifest-first dependencies.

- https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355367
- http://dev.eclipse.org/mhonarc/lists/tycho-user/msg01673.html

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply and for your short introduction to stackoverflow ;-) as you recognized i posted the question on the mailinglist too, but as it not showed up after three days, i decided to post it here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Dependency-resolution is a two-step process in Tycho:

- First, Tycho computes the so-called [target platform](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform), which is
  the set of artifacts that are considered for dependency resolution.
  In this step, Tycho evaluates the POM dependencies according to the
  Maven rules and adds the result to the target platform. Also, all
  Tycho artifacts you have built locally with `mvn install` are added
  to the target platform.
- Then, Tycho resolves your project's dependencies (from the
  MANIFEST.MF, feature.xml, etc.) according to the OSGi rules. Unlike
  in Maven dependencies, OSGi dependencies are typically specified as
  version ranges. So if you write

  ```
  Require-Bundle: my.bundle;bundle-version="1.2.0"
  ```

  you are saying that you want version 1.2.0 or later. You typically don't want to specify an exact version here, because this would have implications on the runtime. But you do want to control what happens at build time, which is why there are various ways to control the content of the target platform.

In your particular case, you have your POM-first artifacts in the target platform in the version specified in the POM. Then, you also seem to be specifying a POM dependency to your Tycho artifacts (which is uncommon, but okay), so you will have the Tycho artifacts **in the specified version** in the target platform. But since you have also built a **newer version** of the Tycho artifacts locally with `mvn install`, these will also be in the target platform. The dependency resolution (step 2) hence has a choice between **two versions**, an will typically pick the later version.

To prevent the locally built artifacts from being added to the target platform, you can delete the file `~/.m2/repository/.meta/p2-local-metadata.properties`. (I'm assuming you already know this, but just to be sure. [Bug 355367](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=355367) will also bring a alternative, more convenient option in 0.16.0.)

And now I finally get to your question why the behaviour is different for POM-first artifacts compared to Tycho artifacts:

- Assume multiple Tycho artifacts are built together in the same reactor. Then each artifact can use the other artifacts as dependencies without needing any specific target platform configuration, e.g. you don't need POM dependencies to the artifacts in the same reactor. (Or in other words: upstream artifacts from the same reactor are automatically part of a module's target platform.) So in order to support re-builds of parts of a Tycho reactor (after a `mvn install` of the full reactor), locally installed Tycho artifacts need to be added to every module's target platform. Tycho can't know if they were originally part of the same reactor, so it just adds them all.
- For POM-first artifacts, the reference to the artifact is always there (through the Maven configuration inheritance), even if only a part of a Tycho reactor is built. Therefore there doesn't need to be any mechanism for picking up any version of the locally built POM-first artifacts, but Tycho can add the exactly specified version to the target platform.

Answer (score 5):

For those interested to force tycho to ignore local artifacts when resolving the target platform, add the CLI tycho.localArtifacts=ignore as in e.g.

```
mvn clean install -Dtycho.localArtifacts=ignore
```

More details can be found on the [Tycho-Target Eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Effective_content_of_the_target_platform)